# fancybox 2: put thumbnails within a parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

Ok so I've recently added '[fancyBox](http://www.fancyapps.com/)' to my site and its great. However I want to place the tumbnails (whose functionality is part of the thumbnails helper, thus in a separate .js file) just under the gallery images.

I first tried to change the divs containing the images (and I assumed thumbnails) however the two are sibling divs with no parent div other than body. I then set about trying to figure out what is actually 'printing' the elements onto the page and I've found a whole bunch of uses of 'wrap'.

For Example:

```
tpl: {
            wrap     : '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>',
            image    : '<img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" />',
            iframe   : '<iframe id="fancybox-frame{rnd}" name="fancybox-frame{rnd}" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen' + (IE ? ' allowtransparency="true"' : '') + '></iframe>',
            error    : '<p class="fancybox-error">The requested content cannot be loaded.<br/>Please try again later.</p>',
            closeBtn : '<a title="Close" class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" href="javascript:;"></a>',
            next     : '<a title="Next" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>',
            prev     : '<a title="Previous" class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" href="javascript:;"><span></span></a>'
        },
```

So first off; whats the **tpl : {},**? What is that? Is it an array? A function? I can't find any documentation talking about something that fits that syntax, which just span me right out.

Secondly I assume that's not the lines where the actual html is being 'printed', just the area that's defining what should be printed and the values within it are called when the html is *actually* printed. ...?
So wouldn't that mean that I could print this (from the thumbnail js file):

```
this.wrap = $('<div id="fancybox-thumbs"></div>').addClass(opts.position).appendTo('body');
        this.list = $('<ul>' + list + '</ul>').appendTo(this.wrap);
```

on the line where the actual html for the images is printed? Bearing in mind they're part of two separate files.

Basically all I need is to have a parent div for both the gallery and the thumbnails. This way I can position the thumbnails according to the size of the gallery. I'm using drupal as well, so pretty much any hard coding of html documents is out, unless its a template obviously.

I tried to figure this out on my onesie however due to my lack of experience and the fact that the main file is 2020 lines long, its highly unlikely I'll be successful. Rather I'll find myself repetitively hitting walls I don't have a clue about, then proceed to lose my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are not too much documentation about the `tpl` API option so I will share with you my findings.

---

1). `whats the tpl : {},?`  : `tpl` stands for *template*, and it's a collection of data entries (json name/value pair format) that returns metadata inside the fancybox function.

```
obj : {
    property-name: value // Boolean (true/false), integer (50, 260.3) or string ("string" ... note the quotes)
}
```

You can use `tpl` to add your own selectors to fancybox if you want to add different css styles like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    tpl: {
        wrap: '<div class="fancybox-wrap mywrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>'
    },
});
```

**Notice** I added the class *`mywrap`* so you can use its selector to add custom css styles (or manipulate it through jQuery) like :

```
/* add a 5px red border around fancybox */
.mywrap {
    border: solid 5px #880000 !important;
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qvFB7/)**

---

2). `Basically all I need is to have a parent div for both the gallery and the thumbnails.`
This has to be seen from different angles.

When you open fancybox two main containers are added (by selector) :

2.a). `.fancybox-overlay`

- it's the semi-transparent overlay on top of your page **AND** behind fancybox
- it's **always** appended to the `body`

2.b). `.fancybox-wrap`

- it's the fancybox box with all its children (navigation and close buttons, content, etc.)
- it's appended to `.fancybox-overlay` **IF** the `locked` option is set to `true` (default value) like :

  ```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      helpers : {
          overlay: {
              locked: true
          }
      }
  });
  ```
- **OR** it's appended to `body` **IF** the `locked` option is set to `false` :

  ```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      helpers : {
          overlay: {
              locked: false
          }
      }
  });
  ```

  **NOTE**: `.fancybox-wrap` will be a sibling of `.fancybox-overlay` in this case.
- it's appended to any designated custom container when using the option `parent` **AND** the `locked` option is set to `false`

  so having this html:

  ```
  <body>
      <div id="mainWrapper"></div>
  </body>
  ```

  ... and

  ```
  $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      parent: "#mainWrapper", // parent div
      helpers : {
          overlay: {
              locked: false
          }
      }
  });
  ```

  ...`.fancybox-wrap` will be appended as a child element of `#mainWrapper` so you can apply your own custom css styles like :

  ```
  #mainWrapper .fancybox-wrap {
      left: 0 !important;
  }
  ```

  See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3w3az/)**

---

3). When you use the thumbnails helper (and linked the proper js and css files), another container is added by fancybox  :

3.a). `#fancybox-thumbs`

- it's always appended to the `body`
- it's a sibling of the `.fancybox-overlay` element

If you require a parent `div` for the `#fancybox-thumbs` container, you could wrap `#fancybox-thumbs` with its new custom parent `div` on the fly using a fancybox callback like :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    helpers: {
        thumbs: {}
    },
    afterShow: function () {
        if ($(".mythumbswrap").length == 0) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("body").find("#fancybox-thumbs").css({
                    // custom css (optional)
                    position: "relative"
                }).wrap("<div class='mythumbswrap' />");
            }, 100);
        }
    },
    afterClose: function () {
        $(".mythumbswrap").remove();
    }
});
```

**Notice** that we first checked if `.mythumbswrap` already existed, which can be true if I am browsing a gallery. If not, we'll add it **BUT** we will need to wait for `#fancybox-thumbs` to be appended to the `body` since it doesn't happen until fancybox is completely added to the DOM.

We used `setTimeout` to set the delay.

Also notice that we removed the parent container `.mythumbswrap` after closing fancybox, otherwise it will remain in the DOM and not added as a wrapper of `#fancybox-thumbs` next time we open fancybox.

Since now `.mythumbswrap` is the *parent* element of `#fancybox-thumbs` we can apply any custom styles like :

```
.mythumbswrap {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF !important;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10000;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7c554/)**

Comment: Ok so what I assume from this, correct me if I'm wrong, is that the 'mythumbswrap' would fit to  the size of the view window and not the gallery. I should have more specific saying something like _"Basically all I need is to have a parent div for both the gallery and the thumbnails **that fits the size of the gallery** so that I can position the thumbnails according to the gallery."_

Comment: You could use `.wrapAll()` to wrap both `.fancybox-overlay` and `#fancybox-thumbs` inside `.mythumbswrap`. Then apply style and size to `.mythumbswrap` at your convenience. My answer is to give you an idea what selectors you would have to be dealing with.

Comment: @Noodlemanny : this is an example how to use `.wrapAll()` http://jsfiddle.net/Evufh/