# Fancybox: Overlay opens inside div as desired, but not content

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I've currently got the Fancybox overlay opening inside my `#main` div as desired, rather than the default behavior of opening inside `body` element.

I did this as suggested in several stackoverflow threads, by changing the jquery.fancybox.js script in this line:

```
this.overlay = $('<div class="fancybox-overlay"></div>').appendTo( parent && parent.length ? parent : 'body' );
```

to this:

```
this.overlay = $('<div class="fancybox-overlay"></div>').appendTo( parent && parent.length ? parent : '#main' );
```

This works for positioning the overlay.

I want Fancybox to then center all popup content within that overlay. However, the first Fancybox content that opens does not center within the overlay, but rather within `body` - this unexpected behavior sometimes puts fancybox content partly outside the overlay. Subsequent fancybox elements **do center within the overlay** - it is only the first loaded element that centers on `body`.

Obviously, Fancybox goes to quite a bit of trouble to calculate viewport dimensions and make it possible center its content within the body element, but in this case I want all elements centered within my target `#main` div, within the `.fancybox-overlay`.

*Edit - changed "parent.lenth", a typo in the original jquery.fancybox.js file, to "parent.length" - as pointed out by djehrame below. Behavior persists unfortuntately.*

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a typo? parent.lenth should be parent.length

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately correcting that typo does not change the behavior. But you're right, and that typo is even in the original jquery.fancybox.js file I just downloaded.

Comment: To be clearer, the overlay does position properly. It's the content within that is incorrectly positioned. I'm not sure but I believe Fancybox calculates _content position_ from _overlay position_, though, since content positioning works as expected on subsequent elements.

Comment: [link](http://andrewnimmo.com/test/recent-work/posters) Click "options" on this example to see the fancybox

Comment: have you tried the `parent` API option? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19689842/1055987, specially No. 2

Comment: Thanks JFK - the `parent` option however does not seem to do govern the parameter I'm trying to set. I guess you could say I'm trying to change the scope - the DOM element - within which Fancybox operates (including the overlay), from `body` to `#main`

Comment: (above comment cont'd) … whereas the `parent` option seems to add a new DOM element. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: There was a valuable comment here earlier which unfortunately got deleted - pointing out that on first load, `.fancybox-wrap` is a *sibling* of `.fancybox-overlay`, while after the second element of the gallery loads, `.fancybox-wrap` is a *child* of `fancybox-overlay` as it should be.